# In what order should navigation bars links be?

Tags: navigation, sort, ordering

I was wondering, what would be the best way to sort website's navigation bar for the best user experience?

Should the user read about me first, information or go directly to see the Services?
Which are users known to click the most regardless of the title/page?

The navigation:

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fh44W9.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

- **About me** = Who am I, what do I do
- **Services** = Information about my products and pricings
- **Info** = Why would you need my products, comparison to other similar services etc.

In which order should these be?

To which page should the "Read More" button direct?

Comment: I think the Info page makes things confusing. Don't all of your pages have information on them? I wouldn't know which one to go to. You either need to give it a better name, merge it with another, or get rid of it.

Comment: What about merging Info and About Me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order of the information should be set by what you want the user to do. For new users the offerings of the site should be first. For returning users put the account at the end.

In lists in general the first two and last items carry the most weight!

The name of sections are also important. Avoid generic titles like 'info' or 'details' as these wont' tell the users what information lies underneath it.

Also 'about' sections should ideally be the page that the users land on, so you version with Home is closest to what the user would expect, but the page they land on could be the about page. In most cases you have only a few seconds to inform the user what the site is about and why they should explore more, you cannot depend on users clicking on navigation.

Lastly, if you can, reduce the information to fit on one page!

Comment: Should I combine the About me and Info?

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on the goal of your website. What is it?

As I understand this is portfolio/services website, thus the goal is to sell your services. 
Why Services are separate from Info? 
Why do you need Read More button? if you don't know what it's for how can anyone tell you?

I believe entice your audience by your services and if they want to find out more they will read more about them and about you. In my opinion the navigation could
 have 2 tabs:

- Home page: where you list services - read more about the service could work here
- About me: CV and contact details(contact at footer as well)